# SAS Export Dataset to Replace a Single Sheet in 2016 Excel File

Tags: excel, sas, export-to-excel

I know this question has already been asked several times, however unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a xlsx file where I have a sheet called "Data" which has raw data (exported from SAS) and then there are other sheets which calculate values based on the "Data" sheet. I need to update the "Data" sheet every month. I would like to be able to export a SAS dataset to this file so that only the "Data" sheet is replaced and all other sheets in the file remain the same.

Previously, I had 64-bit Office 2013 installed onto my computer and I was able to achieve the above by using the below code:

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= work.dataset
            OUTFILE= "file_path\file_name.xlsx" 
            DBMS = excel REPLACE;
     SHEET = "Data";
RUN;
```

However, I now have 32-bit Office 2016 installed onto my computer. When I run the above code, I get an error message saying:

> ERROR: Connect: Class not registered

When I change the code so that "DBMS = xlsx", the code runs, but then the entire file is now replaced and only the "Data" sheet remains.

I am using SAS 9.3.

Comment: Since did not you get any answers, I decided to look it up to try to find it on google. Then, I found t that you apparently have [found it already](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Export-Dataset-to-Replace-a-Single-Sheet-in-2016-Excel-File/m-p/695830). Perhaps, just a suggestion, if it worked for you you could answer your own question here and help others ;)

Comment: PCFILES is the correct answer for your situation or an ODBC connection.

Comment: @LuizZ unfortunately while I received several good answers, none of the solutions were suitable for my particular situation. It appears there is no good way of doing this with SAS 9.3.